# Getting an error while running Liquibase update: Privilege issue

Tags: liquibase

I am getting this error while running Liquibase Update.

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: Error executing SQL SELECT MAX(ORDEREXECUTED) FROM G123.DATABASECHANGELOG: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501

It seems to be some privilege issue on Databasechangelog table.

While the change sets are getting successfully executed, the above error pops up and the value of LOCKED gets set to 1 in the changelog table.

Answer (score 1):

The user that is being used does not seem to have the correct permissions to create/read/update the DATABASECHANGELOG and DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK tables, which are the two tables that Liquibase uses to keep track of which changesets have been applied to the database.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21381783